# Ruby PG gem select field in array format

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql, pg

I have a `postgresql` field that stores a 4-element `array`. I want to select the value of that field, but it's coming back as a `string`:

```
{43.690916,-79.396774,43.700845,-79.37125}
```

I would assume that the `gem` would have known the format of that field and returned an `array` but I am wrong.

How can I get this into an `array` without going through `string` methods?  That would seem like a hack.  Moving from four individual `float` fields to a single `array` field with associated methods, I thought would make records easier to access.

There was no migration, and restrictive to assume this is in `Rails`, which it is not.  Here is the structure:

```
Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                  Default
-----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 loc_id    | integer                |           | not null | nextval('mjtable_loc_id_seq'::regclass)
 locname   | character varying(255) |           |          |
 locbounds | double precision[]     |           |          |
```

Comment: Looks very wrong to store 4 values into a single field of a relational database. Violates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form. Since you can't use string methods for reasons you didn't explain, maybe consider extracting the data from the database using the `SUBSTR()` PG method if the values have the same format and length in all columns?

Comment: That field is bounds of a `GPS` area.  So two `lat/lon` combinations.  Should I move this to an `hstore`?  It just feels strange to use 4 fields as floats for something like this.

Comment: can you update question to include the migration you used to create the field?

Comment: @Rich_F See my updated answer.  This should still work for your use case I think.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, array is still a string in the database so you will only have a string and you would need to deal with that as such.

```
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'pgarray_development') # or whatever db name
data = conn.exec('SELECT * FROM foos').entries
=> [{"id"=>"1", "coords"=>"{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0}"]
data.first['coords'].class
=>String
```

But you can do this

```
conn.type_map_for_results = PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new conn
conn.exec("select coords::float[] from foos").values
=> [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

There are probably other ways to use type casts, see https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home

Comment: He does not mention rails in the original question though. Might be a mistake, not sure.

Comment: This is not `Rails`.  It would be nice when people realize that `Ruby` != `Rails`.  But it is good to know that in `PostgreSQL` that this field is a `string` and is indeed meant to be storage only, for follow-up logic after retrieval.

Comment: @Rich_F yes I updated my answer to show non-rails way

Comment: Ya it's not really a solution.  It works, but I was hoping there was a reason to implement that `field` as an `array`.  I'm currently investigating `hstore`.

Comment: see updated answer, you can type cast your array to float

Comment: Ya it works, but the fact remains that it requires post-processing in the `gem` and `ruby` to flush out any value for comparators.  Ultimately my first goal is to use database tools for this.

Comment: but even pure Postgres works this way:  `select coords from foos limit(1);
      coords
-------------------
 {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0}`